# What are the numbers beside the Awards in Smite?

Tags: smite

In the "list" view of the Awards, there is a white number in the upper right corner.

[image]

For example, the 2000 next to Healer. Is this XP, Favor, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are "achievements points". They serve the same purpose as any achievement system, like Steam or GamerScore, i.e. boasting.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I have been wondering what the upper right number is displayed by your Goodwill level (when you look at your profile). Is that number this "Smite Achievement" score (which gets cut off on my xbox one at the fourth digit)? @Ealhad

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't play Smite. But probably ;)

Comment: i added them up and they accumulate to more than the number i was referring to. do you have a source for this answer?

Comment: It is definitely achievement points. I can confirm this. :)

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat sorry to disagree, but like I said, no number in my profile corresponds to the sum of my unlocked awards. Can you find a source?

Comment: Is it accolades? I'll check this out as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm still so sure this is achievement points.

Comment: @Dpeif: That's because achievements have different levels. For example, the healing achievement has 4 levels: bronze, silver, gold, and platinum. Each level is worth a certain number of points. The points increase for each level. When you achieve a level, the UI replaces the previous level with the information for the next level to achieve. In the event that you have maxed out an achievement, only the top level will be shown. So, I'm not that surprised that summing the numbers yourself doesn't equal. I would expect the value you calculated to be less than what the game displays. Is that right?

Comment: @Ellesedil makes sense, I haven't tried adding the numbers in a while but I get what you mean